# Is there a tool to generate all combinations $C$ where $k=7$, $n=36$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, math-software

I need a tool to generate a list of all combinations (without repetition) of $k=7$ elements in a group of $n=36$ elements (it is over $8$ mln unique combinations).

There is [this](https://www.dcode.fr/combinations), but it has 2000 combinations limit.

I think there should be something of the kind in Matlab, Sage, Maxima, Maple, Mathematica, or some other special utility (Scientific Linux, other specialized packages). Maybe someone can give a hint what tool to use?

More specifically, I need not only to generate those 7-out-of-36 combinations: I need to divide (partition) 36 numbers into 8+ mln of 7-element-sets ans 29-element-sets (remaining). Subsets shall have only natural numbers in range 1..36. Numbers never repeat (within each subset), intersection of 7-partition and 29-partition shall be always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a math question, but still, here is one of many possible solutions (Mathematica):

```
a = Subsets[Range[36], {7}];
Export["out.tmp", a, "List"]
```

Admittedly, this is going to take a while (~4 minutes in my case).

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant answer! Maybe you know how to do it in some non-propriatary math-soft, like Sage, Maxima, Octave, etc.?

Comment: Pity I'm not familiar with any of those. If I'd need it for myself while being without Mathematica, I'd implement it in some general-purpose programming language, but that would take longer than 4 min.

Comment: May I ask you to send me this file if you could to caasdads@bk.ru? Combinations without repetition, n=36, k=7 (7 out of 36). I would appreciate it much. Unfortunately I cannot afford to use proprietary soft...

Comment: I am trying to implement it in java now, using this lib (it generates almost everything ): https://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib   If you ever need an advice about that -  I am at your disposal, I am making use of some its features, but of course it would take hours, not minutes without Mathematica :))).

Comment: https://files.fm/u/h2neb534#_

Answer (score 2):

It is easy enough in R.  For example

```
sevenfrom36 <- combn(36, 7)
```

will give you a matrix with $7$ rows and $8347680$ columns in about $5$ seconds on my machine, with each column being a combination.

The first ten columns are not very exciting

```
> sevenfrom36[,1:10]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5     5
[6,]    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6     6
[7,]    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15    16
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is useful to note that a system like [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) has a command called

```
IteratorOfCombinations
```

that allows you to loop over your combinations without having to write out the (longish) list.

Answer (score 2):

For Matlab/Octave: the command `nchoosek(36, 7)` computes the number $\tbinom{36}{7}$, while `nchoosek(1:36, 7)` generates a $\tbinom{36}{7} \times 7$ matrix whose rows are all the combinations (without repetitions) of $7$ elements in the group of numbers $1, 2, \ldots, 36$. If you instead want the combinations of another group of numbers, then you can encode them in a vector `x` and invoke `nchoosek(x, 7)` (if you also want the combinations to be non-decreasing, then make sure the numbers in `x` are already non-decreasing.)

If you want to do stuff over each combination, then you can use a `for` cycle as follows:

```
for j = nchoosek(1:36, 7)',
    % Do stuff over j' (row form) or over j (column form)
end
```